# Unsupported lookup 'between' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

and I write a query statement in view function like this:

```
from datetime import time
start_time = time(hour=17)
end_time = time(hour=18)
articles = Article.objects.filter(create_time__time__between=(start_time,end_time))
```

but Django raise Exception `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'between' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted.`,[django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#time) says it is right.if I want filter hour between 17 to 18,what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Django syntax for BETWEEN lookups is [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range), not `__between` - that just appears to be a mistake in the `__time` docs.

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(create_time__time__range=(start_time,end_time))
```

(I've submitted a PR to fix the docs.)